# Windows Gadget mailto: link not working

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm creating a Windows Gadget and have found that my mailto links are not working at all.  I have other links that work perfectly like:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="new">Yahoo</a>
```

But when I do this, it doesn't do anything

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a>
```

or I also tried this

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="new">test@test.com</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mailto:` protocol works fine for me in a gadget running on Windows 7 with MS Outlook, and it also worked on my Windows Vista virtual machine *after I had set up an email account* with Windows Live Mail.

I would ensure that you have set up an email account on the machine you're testing with.

Comment: That could be it.  I have gmail and have a plugin that makes it my default mail client and so the mailto links redirect to Gmail, but I don't regularly use IE so I didn't think about that.  When I use IE and go to a website that has a mailto link it pops an Internet Explorer Security  warning about Protected Mode and having to Allow it to open MS Outlook.  That is probably why it doesn't work within the Gadget.  I'm sure it suppresses that warning and doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Jeff: yeah, that sounds like it's probably the issue.